# Problem in cut operation in objective c

Tags: iphone

i am working on file manager application and i have to perform copy paste and cut file operation. i done the copy paste operation. but how can i do the cut file operation.

Comment: Could you post some code to show how copy and paste are done. With that information I might be able to figure out cut.

Comment: i used [NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:path1 toPath:path2 error:&error];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between copy and cut is that cut will move the item instead of copying it, so this is what you want to use:

```
[NSFileManager moveItemAtPath:path1 toPath:path2 error:&error];
```